# How to set expiration time of PhoneNumberTokenProvider in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, phone-number

I am working on an Project in which I need to validate user phone number by SMS.

I am using `AspNet.Identity.PhoneNumberTokenProvider` for the same. I want to set expiration time of the generated `PhoneNumberToken` .

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The `PhoneNumberTokenProvider` class implements `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider` which internally uses `Rfc6238AuthenticationService` to generate the sms validation code. The default expiration time for the validation code is 3 minutes with a variance of 9 minutes. Unfortunately I don't think you can modify the lifespan of the token.

You can check for yourself the classes I mentioned above on [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/85012bd0ac83548f7eab31f0585dae3836935d9d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity) git repo.

Comment: Checked this in 2021. The current implementation of the RFC is in https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs.
Also looks like the variance is of 9 minutes.

Comment: According to commit [Fix comment of variance time for Rfc6238](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/commit/b782674) it appears that the variance was incorrectly stated as 90 secs instead of 9 mins.